# Where is Java's internal classes Metadata stored in memory

Tags: java, jvm, permgen

We know that PermGen or "permanent generation" is where meta-data describing user classes (not the Java's internal classes) and static references stored.
But where exactly are Java's internal classes (i.e. the classes present in rt, resources jar etc) metadata stored exactly?

**I am asking this question in reference to Java versions before 1.8**

Comment: what are *Java's internal classes*?

Comment: By Java's internal classes i mean classes present in rt, resources jar, etc.

Comment: All the classes are stored in the Metaspace.  There is no specific address reserved for classes from a particular jar. Note: in Java 9 there is no rt.jar.  Metspace has no single address in memory and can be in any number of places in native memory in reality.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey, i think i need to edit my question again. I am trying to understand this for java versions before 1.8. Is it same for java 1.6, 1.7 as well?

Comment: Java 7 and previous had a PermGen which was at a fixed location and size.  However knowing the location is not something you would be able to use.

Comment: We can modify the permgen min and max size. 
I don't want to use the location where java's/jre internal class's metadata is stored. This is for my own understanding of java's memory management!

Comment: There is no difference between what you call “user classes” and “internal classes”.

Comment: After all the comments above and me researching the java docs and all, i think you guys are right and in words of @Holger, there is no difference between a "user class" and "internal class". All these meta-data go to Permgen, when that class loads and are cleared once those are unreachable. Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the comments above and researching the java docs and all, it seems like there is no difference between a "user class" and "internal class" in terms of how there metadata is stored on permgen. All these meta-data go to Permgen, when that class loads and are cleared once those are unreachable.